# Android app randomly exiting app with no error what do i need to do?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to implement this loading future when implemented all the way the app will open it will show the loading circle but then will randomly turn the app off and exit with no error I'm unaware of why this keeps on happening or what exactly am I doing wrong I have listed my code for my main activity Java if someone could please help me that would be amazing.

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String ShowOrHideWebViewInitialUse = "show";
    private ProgressBar spinner;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.my_webview);
        Button reloadBtn = findViewById(R.id.reload_btn);
        ProgressBar progress = findViewById(R.id.my_progress);
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView5);

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if (ShowOrHideWebViewInitialUse.equals("show")) {
                    webView.setVisibility(webView.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                ShowOrHideWebViewInitialUse = "hide";
                spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });


        if (isNetworkAvailable(this)) {

            webView.loadUrl("https://racks.tk");

            reloadBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(this, "No internet. Please check internet connection and try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            reloadBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }



        reloadBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (isNetworkAvailable(MainActivity.this)) {
                    reloadBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    webView.loadUrl("https://racks.tk");
                } else {

                    reloadBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No internet. Please check internet connection and try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @SuppressLint("NonConstantResourceId")
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.my_webview);
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.site:
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://racks.tk")));
                break;
            case R.id.ribbon:
                webView.reload();
                break;
            case R.id.support:
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://racks.tk/support")));
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }



    public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {

        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        if (connectivityManager != null) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                NetworkCapabilities capabilities = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(connectivityManager.getActiveNetwork());
                return capabilities != null && (capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) || capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR) || capabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_ETHERNET));
            } else {
                NetworkInfo activeNetwork = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                return activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you must receiving security exception as you are accessing network state.

Please add below permission in you manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

In case you face any error and want to debug from android studio you can put "No Filter" instead "Show only selected application" sometime this works.

[image]

Your app is running successfully!

[image]

Comment: unfortunately that is not the issue that was in there before the implementation loading screen it has to do with an issue of the loading screen but I do not know what it is everything with the internet works with the app @Maulik Togadiya

Comment: In case you face any error and want to debug from android studio you can put "No Filter" instead "Show only selected application" sometime this works.

Comment: Where might that be at?

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: I'm still unable to exactly determine what the issue is nothing pops up when I open the app and log cat

Comment: I checked again and nothing red pops up @Maulik Togadiya

Comment: did you try with no filter?
first clear all logs with selecting No filter and just launch app
For more filter you can change verbose setting to Error

Comment: this is what i get what running before crashing https://pastebin.com/8fCUpsDx

Comment: my i know the android version of device you are running app?

Comment: Also it seems like somthing is wrong with network check code so let's try to put isNetworkAvailable function in try/catch block.